# Loading site's 404 page instead of redirecting to it based on URL starting part

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to figure out how to load a chosen page (a 404 page) on the condition that the URL starts with img/galery/. We changed our image repositiory when we changed an eshop backend solution and a lot of crawlers are still trying to index our old images. Like an year+ old URLs. There's no way we could map old img URLs onto the new ones so i want to force a 404 there, because there are some htaccess rules that make those URLs a 301 and the crawler may think those images still exists, but they don't.

So basicly what i want to do is for **any URL that starts with img/galery/ to** load our **site's /404/ page with no redirect**. I just want to skip any redirect or any URL manipulation whatsoever so the crawers are given clear answer. I've tried hard, but as usual htaccess is really just black magic to me:

```
RewriteEngine On

# does not load the site's 404 page, just shows a plain (apache?) 404 page, but reacts on any URL starting with img/galery/
RewriteRule ^img/galery/ 404/ [R=404,NC,L]

# redirects to 404 page, but that's not what i wanna do
RewriteRule ^img/galery/ 404/ [R=301,NC,L]

# also redirects
RewriteRule ^img/galery/ 404/ [R,NC,L]

# does nothing
RewriteRule ^img/galery/ 404/ [NC,L]

# does nothing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^img/galery [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ 404/ [L]
```

I've tried many solutions from SO or other sites, none is working. What am i missing here? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not possible to use RewriteRule to load dynamic 404/ page, so i made new 404.php file that imitates its mechanics.

I haven't found any other more direct solution than this, but maybe it will help somebody with the same struggle i had.